# How to write a postgresql function to sum grouped metrics from a daily report table

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write a function that sums up reports for a given date range.

I have 3 tables:

- `campaign` it has a primary key (`campaign.id`) and the portfolio the campaign is related to (`campaign.portfolio_id`)
- `report_campaign` is a daily report table, each row represents some metrics for a specific date(`report_campaign.report_date`) and the campaign the report is for `report_campaign.campaign_id`
- `portfolio_summary` This table doesn't contain any data, but a tool I use needs this table to understand the information returned by the function.

I have written a function that I think should work but I am seeing some strange behaviour that I do not understand. When I call the function it does not filter out anything by the dates I pass in instead it includes all data in the table, even when I call the function with a start date after the end date I receive all the data in the table. I have some similar functions that accept start_date and end_date in an identical fashion and they work.

Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.portfolio_summary_between_dates(start_date date, end_date date)
 RETURNS SETOF portfolio_summary
 LANGUAGE sql 
 STABLE
AS $$ WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    campaign.portfolio_id AS id, 
    sum(clicks) AS clicks, 
    sum(impressions) AS impressions, 
    sum(attributed_sales_14d) AS sales, 
    sum(cost) AS total_cost 
  FROM 
    report_campaign 
    INNER JOIN campaign ON report_campaign.campaign_id = campaign.id 
  WHERE 
    report_campaign.report_date >= start_date 
    AND report_campaign.report_date <= end_date 
    AND campaign.portfolio_id IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY 
    campaign.portfolio_id
) 
SELECT 
  *, 
  (clicks :: float / NULLIF(impressions, 0)) AS ctr, 
  (total_cost / NULLIF(sales, 0)) AS acos, 
  (total_cost / NULLIF(clicks, 0)) AS cpc 
FROM 
  cte $$
```

I am using Postgres 10.6

Comment: The `start_date` and the `end_date` are not used anywhere in your query.  Can you please explain how you expect that the query will use those values if they are not referenced in the query?

Comment: @MikeOrganek they are used in the WHERE statement `report_campaign.report_date >= start_date AND report_campaign.report_date <= end_date `.

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  I see it now. How do you know that this query is returning results calculated from outside of the date range passed into the function?

Comment: @MikeOrganek  `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM report_campaign WHERE report_date >= start_date AND report_date <= end_date` (with dates substituted in) returns 0. I'm pretty sure there isn't anything wrong with my approach and suspect I've made a minor mistake or typo somewhere.

Comment: FWIW I solved the problem, the `campaign` table had a `start_date` and `end_date` column. I renamed the variables and everything worked as expected.